# Failure of 1 SSD in Raid-0 that was bootdrive stopping computer from booting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, raid

I've spent 4+ hours searching this site and Google for someone to have/address my issue, and have had no luck so far, so I was wondering if someone could help me. Thank you!

My computer has 2 32 GB SSD's raided together (Raid-0; I know,I know, but I didn't build the computer myself), from which my computer boots. I have a 1TB regular Hard drive besides for that. I believe 1 of the 2 32GB SSD's failed, as my computer can only find one of them when it boots and I go to BIOS, and it can't load windows obviously. I attempted to hook up the SSD's to an external computer, and it could only read one of them (though it couldn;t actually read anything, but it did registed on the computer) while the other one didn't which leads me to beleive it had died.

I would like to relaoad windows onto the remaining good ssd drive, but I don;t know how to. I start the computer with only one connected, and it goes "scanning drives..." and then I get an 0xc000000e error. I have tried to go into the BIOS to change things, but nothing seems to help. I have tried to get access to the Raid by using Ctrl+I, but it just leads me to a "windows boot menu" which gives me the option of windows 7, which just leads to the same error as above, or a memory diagnostic, which leads to the error after running as well.

Anything you could tell me to help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

P.S. In the meantime, I'd love to be able to put windows onto my 1TB drive and just boot from there, so I can at least have a usable computer. Not sure how to do that though, as it doesn't even give me the option to load windows anytime.

Comment: Please clean up your question by removing personal comments like you googled etc all we care about is your problem and what have you tried so far

Comment: What is your server model ?

Comment: @SeanClt I just wanted to point out that I had done some research before asking, and wasn't just wasting everyone's time. However, if it's inappropriate, I'll remove it.

Also, this is on my desktop computer, not a server.

Comment: Still it helps to have a well formatted question like have sections where you describe hardware and issues in separate passages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Rebuild RAID***

1. This might Not be in your bios
2. Try Ctrl S or F looks at menu for other shortcuts to access your RAID configuration
3. Delete logical disc
4. Create a new logical disc
5. Boot again from Windows media and reinstall on new logical disc

***Change boot order***
To fix the issue where it's not letting you boot from anything other than HDD go to bios and change boot order and maybe add a CD as bootable before HDD
Assuming you have a bootable CD

You would have to reinstall the OS as part of the OS that was on failed disc is gone

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I can access my raid configuration through ctrl-F. However, it leads me to [this screen](http://imgur.com/Pf2lcBm) , and nothing I do there seems to help. I can post what screen results from each of those options if it would help. Unless raid configuration refers to something else.

Comment: You have to delete existing LD and create new one again

Comment: Ok, I deleted LD, and created a new one. I set it to Raid Ready. I then rebooted (with the windows installation disk in) and it scanned the drives - fine. Then it went to loading windows... and went straight back to the error screen. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Go to bios and change your boot order boot from a cd or something and then install Windows

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) 

If I could bother you with one other question: Now that its running, I want to use a system image to restore my computer back to what it was (as much as possible) before the drive crashed. The image is on my 1 TB drive. However, it won't let me use that to load the image from, as it says that it needs to wipe the drive its running on, and tells me to boot from somewhere else and run the restore. So I booted from the cd, and it still won;t let me, giving me the same message. Any thoughts?

Comment: My recommendation if the image is like those windows backup image you might be able to mount it by going to disk management and then just copy paste your data reloading might be tricky so can't comment

Comment: I am new - sorry about that. Done. Thank you so much for your help!