# RAID-0 SSD failure: I/O error, err_mask=0x4

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, raid

**Set up**

I have an **ASUS** `UX301LA-DE022H`. It contains two **SSD SanDisk** `SD6SP1M-256G-1102`, 256G each, configured as an Intel Firmware RAID 0 (a.k.a. fake RAID).

**What happened**

I was using Windows normally. Went away for a few minutes and when I came back, the PC would display a black screen and would only boot to the UEFI configuration screen with no boot options.

So the PC has not endured any shock/physical damage. At this point I suspect a messy Windows update or a software/physical drive failure.

**In a nutshell**

One of the SSD is not detected anymore, making the whole RAID 0 disk invalid. The most relevant error from `dmesg` is `failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)`.

What is the problem? Is it a physical failure? What is the most likely component to fail? I would be curious to know which electronic component failed in that case.

How would a data recovery company proceed to recover the data? Would they replace the SSD controller? Would they look for a dead resistor?

---

Find below all details:

**Investigation**

- the computer takes 120 seconds to display the UEFI configuration screen
- there is no boot options available from the UEFI configuration screen
- one SSD is functional (but it's only half of the RAID 0!):

  - it is detected while booting on Linux USB stick

    ```
    > dmesg|grep ata2
    [    3.590698] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7d22000 port 0xf7d22180 irq 43
    [   51.454606] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
    [   51.455389] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
    [   51.456504] ata2.00: ATA-8: SanDisk SD6SP1M256G1102, X231302, max UDMA/133
    [   51.456510] ata2.00: 500118192 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
    [   51.457752] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
    [   51.459283] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    ```
  - when the SSD is by itself, the PC starts immediately without any problem
  - when the SSD is by itself, it is correctly detected by the UEFI configuration

[image: ssd-working-uefi]

- one SSD is not functional:

  - it is NOT detected while booting on Linux USB stick

    ```
    > dmesg|grep ata1
    [    3.590697] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7d22000 port 0xf7d22100 irq 43
    [    3.904513] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
    [    9.013343] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
    [    9.013356] ata1.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
    [    9.327983] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
    [   19.466671] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
    [   19.466683] ata1.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
    [   19.466690] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
    [   19.781305] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
    [   50.826666] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
    [   50.826678] ata1.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
    [   51.141298] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
    ```
  - when the SSD is by itself, the PC starts slowly
  - when the SSD is by itself, it is incorrectly detected by the UEFI configuration

[image: ssd-not-working-uefi]

- both SATA ports are OK: I tried the functional SSD on each port and it was correctly and quickly detected.
- when both SSD are present,  the UEFI configuration screen shows both disks. That last point puzzles me: it seems like the PC is able to know there are two SSDs, but times out trying to reach one of them.

[image: both-ssd]

- both SSD present no visual damage

[image: ssd-1]
[image: ssd-2]

Additional info (only showing relevant part):

```
> blkid
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"

> lsscsi -L
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      SanDisk SD6SP1M2 302   /dev/sdb
  device_blocked=0
  iocounterbits=32
  iodone_cnt=0x6d
  ioerr_cnt=0x2
  iorequest_cnt=0x6d
  queue_depth=31
  queue_type=simple
  scsi_level=6
  state=running
  timeout=30
  type=0

> smartctl -iA /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.14.15-1-ARCH] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SanDisk SD6SP1M256G1102
Serial Number:    141196400698
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 beb8b143a
Firmware Version: X231302
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      Unknown (0x0010)
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jul 22 03:01:37 2018 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 4
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   253   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       3184
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       16004
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       19
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       117
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       379
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       27
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       39
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   058   047   ---    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 18/47)
212 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
230 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       90
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   004    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       7187
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       1266
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       1203
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Other Linux commands such as `dmidecode`, `fdisk`, `lsblk` and `lspci` did not provide more relevant information.

NB: I found some related questions such as [Failure of 1 SSD in Raid-0 that was bootdrive stopping computer from booting](https://superuser.com/questions/1039586/failure-of-1-ssd-in-raid-0-that-was-bootdrive-stopping-computer-from-booting) and [How to fix missing RAID1 drive](https://superuser.com/questions/438840/how-to-fix-missing-raid1-drive) However I was not able to access the RAID configuration screen at startup.

If possible, I would like to retrieve the data from those disks. At this point, I'm not interested into scratching the data and turning the remainig disk into a single disk. Eventually, I will contact a data recovery company but I would like to know what is the problem and if there is anything I can do.

Please refer to **In a nutshell** section for the question.

Comment: One if your SSDs has failed catastrophically (what you describe is a typical SSD failure). You recover from backup or pay $lots$ to a specialist recovery firm. Poking arround with data recovery tools on your PC won't get the data off.

Comment: Ok I'm fine with that conclusion, but how would a data recovery company proceed to recover the data? What is the most likely component to fail? Would they replace the SSD controller? Would they look for a dead resistor? (I've updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

this is a kernel bug, i am using debian 11 with kernel 5.10 and have the same issue, once i upgraded to kernel 5.18 it was gone.